# How to extract the output of the survCIS() function from the IcenReg package?

Tags: survival-analysis, confidence-interval

I would like to extract the lower and upper value of a survival curve fitted with the icenReg package in order to use it in a ggplot graph.

I know how to store these value in an object but I don't manage to extract them from this object :

```
library(icenReg)
data("IR_diabetes")
flatPrior_fit <- ic_bayes(cbind(left, right) ~ gender, data = IR_diabetes, model = "po", dist = "gamma")
invCDF_ests <- survCIs(flatPrior_fit)
```

How do I extract these values, and how can I use them to obtain the confidence interval of the curve in ggplot  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at its structure:

```
str(invCDF_ests)
Reference class 'surv_cis' [package "icenReg"] with 4 fields
 $ cis     :List of 1
  ..$ baseline: num [1:20, 1:5] 0.025 0.075 0.125 0.175 0.225 0.275 0.325 0.375 0.425 0.475 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "Percentile" "estimate (mean)" "estimate (median)" "lower" ...
 $ call    : language ic_bayes(formula = cbind(left, right) ~ gender, data = IR_diabetes, model = "po", dist = "gamma")
 $ newdata :Formal class 'uninitializedField' [package "methods"] with 2 slots
  .. ..@ field    : chr "newdata"
  .. ..@ className: chr "ANY"
 $ ci_level: num 0.95
 and 19 methods, of which 5 are  possibly relevant:
   all_lines, fit_one_row, initialize, one_lines, show#envRefClass
```

Then notice that the `cis` element of that structure appears to be a regular R list that contains a matrix named `baseline` and the `cis` element is along side three other elements as well as a slew of non-displayed methods. It is, however, a reference class object commonly referred to as R6. I don't have a lot of experience with R6 structures and methods, but naively tried to extract it with "$" since that was being shown by the `str` output, ....  and had immediate success:

```
invCDF_ests$cis$baseline
      Percentile estimate (mean) estimate (median)     lower     upper
 [1,]      0.025        6.953697          6.955755  6.485497  7.393824
 [2,]      0.075        8.874299          8.878339  8.415723  9.295514
 [3,]      0.125       10.089455         10.091384  9.638875 10.514400
 [4,]      0.175       11.068418         11.069332 10.627237 11.488847
 [5,]      0.225       11.929793         11.928560 11.490618 12.344999
 [6,]      0.275       12.724884         12.722080 12.283112 13.136176
 [7,]      0.325       13.482080         13.482863 13.042530 13.897173
 [8,]      0.375       14.219952         14.220951 13.783115 14.639034
 [9,]      0.425       14.952450         14.953364 14.509479 15.379580
[10,]      0.475       15.691488         15.693712 15.245050 16.129615
[11,]      0.525       16.448540         16.449714 15.992385 16.895773
[12,]      0.575       17.235948         17.236388 16.759356 17.703037
[13,]      0.625       18.068360         18.069621 17.566506 18.563556
[14,]      0.675       18.964750         18.964280 18.439468 19.492435
[15,]      0.725       19.951830         19.954490 19.392602 20.516102
[16,]      0.775       21.070620         21.072578 20.464390 21.676400
[17,]      0.825       22.391076         22.390087 21.730446 23.057110
[18,]      0.875       24.051236         24.051829 23.313166 24.814614
[19,]      0.925       26.398369         26.391658 25.537376 27.296126
[20,]      0.975       30.982438         30.972453 29.838112 32.221068
```

I'm assuming that you know how to use "[" to extract results from R matrices, so I consider the question fully answered.